# Bad resut reading barcode with ZBar Android

Tags: android, zbar

this is my first post here and I will try to explain well my question. I have ZBar(http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) integrated in an Android app and it works but sometimes the reader reads wrong barcodes, i.e., I am reading a real barcode (8410100002026) and the ZBar reads 8470700008026.

Whats the problem? Is there any way to adjust the values of ZBar?

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: both values are apparently valid, and very similar, so it can happen, I guess.

Comment: Is there another barcode reader similar to ZBar with respect to integration? I know Zxing, but it works with intent, and I need start or stop ZBar when I need it.

Answer (score 0):

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/ is not the most popular library to read BarCode.

Maybe have a look at https://github.com/zxing/zxing Its a popular lib to read BarCode for Android  and check if result of reads are better.

Threre's an app on store to test :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android

Comment: I know Zxing, but it works with intent, and I need start or stop ZBar when I need it.

Comment: Zxing is an app but also a stand-alone library. you could include library in your project without need of ZXing app.

Comment: I can integrate ZXing library, but the problem is that ZXing not allow to start or stop camera instance when I want. When I tried this library I couldn't, now I don't know if is possible